# Soft Keyboard + Hard keyboard at same time in webview

Tags: android, android-webview, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

I am creating an webview and I need to force the softkeyboard when any input is focused in the webpage.

I have tried many things that I found and nothing seems to work.

I have tried:
1)

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
 imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

2)

```
webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
 webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
   {
    @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
      switch (event.getAction())
      {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (!v.hasFocus())
            {
                v.requestFocus();
            }
            break;
       }
      return false;
    }
   });
```

And some other things.

I managed to make it work on a samsung with root but in my nexus 7 also with root i can't.

Any help would be apreciated.
Thx

Comment: what's with the hard (physical I guess) keyboard?

Comment: yesm hard is the physical keyboard, the answer below helps to do that, but I need to do it by code and not using the configs from the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could detect if there is a keyboard present, and if not show softkeyboard for the needed view/item

sample code:

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().keyboard == 0)
{
     InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
     imm.showSoftInput(** view/item **, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT); 
}
```

Comment: The thing is that I need both working at same time because the hard-keyboard will be a barcode scanner.

Comment: then your sample code 1 what you have tried should work, but are you using a tablet then its possible that you need to enable some settings on your tablet and not in your code.

Comment: Yep it was just set the phisical keyboar to off and the phisical keyboard still works and now the soft keyboard show also :D.